# How can I get data from JSON array in SWIFT?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

[from this link](https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Journey/JourneyResults/Victoria/to/Bank?nationalSearch=False&timeIs=Departing&journeyPreference=LeastTime&walkingSpeed=Average&cyclePreference=None&alternativeCycle=False&alternativeWalking=True&applyHtmlMarkup=False&useMultiModalCall=False&walkingOptimization=False&app_id=6573044a&app_key=7a97df35339dc68625384077a5e07304) I would like to get the **commonName**

I tried this but it didn't work?!

```
let commonName = object["toLocationDisambiguation"][0]["disambiguationOptions"][1]["place"][2]["commonName"].stringValue
```

Comment: try this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908496/how-to-retrieve-data-from-json-array-and-display-in-textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908496/how-to-retrieve-data-from-json-array-and-display-in-textview)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 (Normal)**

```
if let toLocationDisambiguation = object["toLocationDisambiguation"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    if let disambiguationOptions = toLocationDisambiguation["disambiguationOptions"] as? Array<AnyObject> {
        if let first = disambiguationOptions.first as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let place = first["place"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let commonName = place["commonName"] as! String
                print("Common Name: ", commonName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2 (Type Aliases)**

```
typealias MyDictionary = [String: AnyObject]
typealias MyArray = [MyDictionary]

if let toLocationDisambiguation = object["toLocationDisambiguation"] as? MyDictionary {
    if let disambiguationOptions = toLocationDisambiguation["disambiguationOptions"] as? MyArray {
        if let first = disambiguationOptions.first {
            if let place = first["place"] as? MyDictionary {
                let commonName = place["commonName"] as! String
                print("Common Name: ", commonName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 3 (SwiftyJSON for Objective-C like syntax)**

Take a look at [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

```
let object = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
let json = JSON(object)
let commonName = json["toLocationDisambiguation"]["disambiguationOptions"][0]["place"]["commonName"].stringValue
print("Common Name: ", commonName)
```

Comment: I am using SwiftyJSON so I tried what you suggested:

`if let disambiguations = object["toLocationDisambiguation"] as? MyArray {
                if let commonName = disambiguations.first as? MyDictionary {
                    let commonName = object["commonName"].stringValue
                }
            }`

now I get the error: downcast form 'MyDictionay?' to 'MyDictionary'

Comment: I fixed my code. Basically, get rid of the `as? MyDictionary` as it's unnecessary.

Comment: thanks but I'm really stuck, not sure how I'm supposed to use your syntax
`for (_,object):(String, JSON) in readableJSON {
            typealias MyDictionary = [String: AnyObject]
            typealias MyArray = [MyDictionary]
            if let disambiguations = object["toLocationDisambiguation"] as? MyArray {
                if let first = disambiguations.first {
                   let commonName = disambiguations
                  NSLog("Dis: \(disambiguations)")
                }
            }
            commonNameArray.append(commonName)
            NumberOfRows = commonNameArray.count`

Comment: Sorry if I confused things, I fixed my answer now.

Comment: thanks, the SwiftyJSON one worked although it's not looping in my for loop

`let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)
let object = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
let json = JSON(object)
for (_,object):(String, JSON) in readableJSON {
let commonName = json["toLocationDisambiguation"]["disambiguationOptions"][0]["place"]["commonName"].stringValue commonNameArray.append(commonName)`